# Как создать токен персонального доступа на github

Tags: git, github

Я воспользовался командой git push и он потребовал у меня токен персонального доступа. Я начал искать, что это такое и как его получить. Везде пишут, что нужно зайти в settings, а затем в developer settings. Однако у меня нет вкладки developer settings. Как мне установить этот токен?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: настройки профиля, а не репозитория

Answer (score 3):

Нужен другой settings - не проекта а пользователя (в правом верхнем углу кликаем иконку с аватаркой - в выпадающем меню в самом низу - Settings). Далее на открывшейся странице справа меню - в самом низу Developer settings. После перехода по этой ссылке откроется страница где можно создать и скопировать персональный токен.
Сохраняете его в своей секретной папочке и используете в дальнейшем для авторизации.
В командной строке это будет выглядеть примерно так:
git push https://<ТОКЕН>@github.com/<ИМЯ ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ>/<НАЗВАНИЕ РЕПОЗИТОРИЯ>.git

[image: ссылка на генерацию токена]

Но, вообще говоря, есть еще один способ сделать git push, при этом не получив "сообщений об ошибке", связанных с авторизацией. Это - так называемая "авторизация по ключам".

Обратите внимание, что в командах, которые предлагает "скопировать" github присутствует такой параметр, как протокол:

[image: github protocols]

И для https требуется токен, а для git - не требуется. Зато для git требуется импортировать публичную часть ключа в github, но это хорошо описано, например, здесь:

https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: `push` по адресу `https://` давно запретили. можно через `ssh` : `ssh и gpg keys` - `new ssh key` копировать туда **открытый** `.pub` ключ.